# List All dates based on the current date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to do something like this, 
If I choose current date of month it should give me result like (lets say for today)

```
 1. 04/01/2014        04/01/2014
 2. 04/02/2014        04/01/2014
 3. 04/02/2014        04/02/2014
 4. 04/03/2014        04/01/2014
 5. 04/03/2014        04/02/2014
 6. 04/03/2014        04/03/2014
```

And so on for any date, like for next date it should go up to 4th of april. Is there any way to do this in Oracle.
Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: you need to list date ranges for all days in that month until the current day?

Comment: yes Thats exactly what I am looking for, I give any day in where condition and that result would list all dates till that day in a manner which I mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT to_date('04-APR-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY') ddate -- Your Date here
                 FROM dual),
dates1 AS (SELECT trunc(ddate, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1 ddate1
             FROM dates
          CONNECT BY trunc(ddate, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1 <= trunc(ddate))
SELECT ddate1, trunc(ddate1, 'MM') + LEVEL -1
  FROM dates1
 CONNECT BY trunc(ddate1, 'MM') + LEVEL -1 <= ddate1
   AND PRIOR ddate1 = ddate1
   AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;
```

Output:

```
DDATE1  TRUNC(DDATE1,'MM')+LEVEL-1
4/1/2014    4/1/2014
4/2/2014    4/1/2014
4/2/2014    4/2/2014
4/3/2014    4/1/2014
4/3/2014    4/2/2014
4/3/2014    4/3/2014
4/4/2014    4/1/2014
4/4/2014    4/2/2014
4/4/2014    4/3/2014
4/4/2014    4/4/2014
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Its working, Sorry I am a newbie and dont know how to use Connect By level, Could you please explain me the use of connect by here in sinle line. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Connect by is basically used if some relationship has to be made between parent and child records. [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) and some hands on will let you understand more clearly.

Comment: Cool, I will have a look into it. Thanks again.

Comment: San, May I ask one more question, What is the purpose of using LEVEL keyword here.

Comment: Well, `LEVEL` is a pseudo column in Oracle that is used in hierarchical query to identify the hierarchy level, it must be used with `connect by`. In this case, you are setting the hierarchy using `CONNECT BY trunc(ddate, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1 <= trunc(ddate)` where the current row decides the fate of its child row based on condition `trunc(ddate, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1 <= trunc(ddate)`, whether to produce it or not. `LEVEL` here tells where the current row falls in the hierarchy.